# Is my proof true?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Problem: If $$c:=\frac{a^n+b^n}{(ab)^{n-1}+1},$$ where $a, b, n\in \mathbb{N}$ are such that $c\in\mathbb{N},$ then $c$ is an $n$th power.

Proof: In order to show, it is clear that we need to express $c$ as $c=t^n$ for some $t\in\mathbb{N}$, isn't it?

So let us consider $a=t^{\alpha}, b=t^{\beta}$. Why? Because unless $a, b$ themselves are power some other $t\in\mathbb{N}$, then statement will not be true in general. This is a crucial observation. We are given that $a, b$ are integers (WOLOG we have chosen as positive integers) and hence if $c$ is supposed to be as $t^n$ then $a, b$ have to be some power of $t$; Otherwise, contradiction will arrive.

So we have $$c=\frac{a^n+b^n}{(ab)^{n-1}+1}$$
$$i.e. c =\frac{(t^\alpha)^n+(t^\beta)^n}{(t^{\alpha+\beta})^{n-1}+1}$$
$$i.e. c =\frac{t^{n\beta}(t^{n\alpha-n\beta})+1}{t^{(\alpha+\beta)(n-1)}+1}  $$

Intuition says that we can choose $\beta=1$. But that would be particular stage. So let $\beta=\beta_0$. Now in order to make $c$ as integer, we must have 
$$t^{(\alpha+\beta)(n-1)}+1 \mid t^{n\alpha-n\beta}+1$$ which is true iff $$(\alpha+\beta_0)(n-1)\mid (n\alpha-n\beta_0)$$
$$\text{iff}\; (\alpha+\beta_0)(n-1)s=n\alpha-n\beta_0 \; \text{for some}\; s\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$\text{so}\; \alpha=\frac{-\beta_0(2n-1)}{(n-1)s-n}$$

We choose $s$ in such a way that $\alpha$ is in $\mathbb{N}$. For the sake of simplicity we take $s=-1$ then $\alpha=\beta_0(2n-1)$.
 Thus we have $a=t^{\alpha}=t^{\beta_0 (2n-1)}, b=t^{\beta_0}, \beta_0 \in\mathbb{N}.$ And consequently $c=t^{n\beta_0}$. Since $c$ should be $n$th power, so it follows that $\beta_0=1$ and hence $\alpha=2n-1$ so that $c=t^n$. We are done.

I know that duplicate post is forbidden in this group and as a group member, I abide by the rules. But still I am posting again this INMO problem just to know if there is any mistake in my proof. If yes, I would be obliged to anyone who will reply it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know already several post have been done on it, I have seen them also. But since my proof I have not found so far, so I post it here. Also I was unable to give the links where I have seen it before in MSE. Please tell me about it for future purpose. Thank you

Comment: @vadim But, the question says "If $a, b, n\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $c$ defined above "is in $\mathbb{N}$" then ...."
Because of this, i think your claim does not hold here or violate any thing. Am I right?

Comment: @Anjan Yes you've restricted the hypothesis to cases when $c$ is a natural number.

Comment: If you know of other posts related, it would be good to reference them, so people could see what work has been done.

Comment: @RossMillikan Definitely I would like to do that. Please tell me how to provide HTML link here? Just give me the command for once, I will immediately provide the link

Comment: If you click on the edit button, there is an icon looking like a chain.  If you click on that, it will allow you to insert a link.  You put the URL into the window that pops up, then (after dismissing it) between the square brackets you can put the text you want in blue.  In comments you can use [text](URL)

Comment: You can also use the [text](URL) format in your post, not just in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to show, it is clear that we need to express $c$ as $c=t^n$ for some $t\in\mathbb{N}$, isn't it?

Yes, that's true.

> So let us consider $a=t^{\alpha}, b=t^{\beta}$.

Here's where your first issue comes up. What is $t$? Our goal, here, is to *find* some $t\in\Bbb N$ such that $c=t^n,$ but we haven't found it, yet!

> Why? Because unless $a, b$ themselves are power some other $t\in\mathbb{N}$, then statement will not be true in general. This is a crucial observation. We are given that $a, b$ are integers (WOLOG we have chosen as positive integers) and hence if $c$ is supposed to be as $t^n$ then $a, b$ have to be some power of $t$; Otherwise, contradiction will arrive.

I'm not sure what you're saying, here, but it seems that you're bringing in an additional assumption to avoid some contradiction. (Also, $a,b$ are assumed to be natural numbers, not just integers.) But even if we knew what $t$ was, how do we know that $a,b$ are both powers of $t$? (If $\alpha,\beta$ are supposed to be real numbers, then we don't have to worry about that, of course. We simply put $\alpha=\log_ta$ and $\beta=\log_tb,$ whatever $t$ is....)

> So we have $$c=\frac{a^n+b^n}{(ab)^{n-1}+1}$$
>   $$i.e. c =\frac{(t^\alpha)^n+(t^\beta)^n}{(t^{\alpha+\beta})^{n-1}+1}$$
>   $$i.e. c =\frac{t^{n\beta}(t^{n\alpha-n\beta})+1}{t^{(\alpha+\beta)(n-1)}+1}  $$

How did you get from the second line to the third? Did you mean to say $$c=\frac{t^{n\beta}(t^{n\alpha-n\beta}+1)}{t^{(\alpha+\beta)(n-1)}+1},$$ perhaps?

> Intuition says that we can choose $\beta=1$.

We *cannot* choose $\beta.$ It is determined uniquely by $a,b,n.$ In any case, if we *could* choose $\beta=1,$ then it would follow that $b=t,$ so $c=t^n=b^n,$ but this hardly seems likely. Neither can we choose $\alpha.$ After this, your proof attempt is completely off track, as it is based on an error.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. I have understand the logic of yours and the flaws in my arguments. It was a healthy discussion for me after all. Thank you very much again for pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that, while you can only accept one answer, you can upvote any that you find useful.

Answer (score 2):

While the result to be proved may be correct, your proof of the result is not correct. The problematic part is shown below:

> So let us consider $a=t^{\alpha}, b=t^{\beta}$. Why? Because unless $a, b$ themselves are power some other $t\in\mathbb{N}$, then statement will not be true in general. This is a crucial observation. We are given that $a, b$ are integers (WOLOG we have chosen as positive integers) and hence if $c$ is supposed to be as $t^n$ then $a, b$ have to be some power of $t$; Otherwise, contradiction will arrive.

**Counterexample:** Take $n=2, a=8, b=30$, then $c=\frac{8^2+30^2}{8(30)+1}=4=2^2$, which is perfectly consistent with the result to be proved. Unfortunately, contrary to what you claimed in the paragraph quoted above, we cannot write $a=8=t^{\alpha}$ and $b=30=t^{\beta}$. You seem to be "handwaving" this step, simply claiming that if $a$ and $b$ are not powers of $t$, we will magically get some contradiction.

P.S. A discussion of the result can be found [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=349211).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear that $a,b$ are powers of $t$, but you assume it.  Then you say "power some other $t$" but  later assume it is the same.  Which is it?  It looks like you mean some other power of $t$.  You say WOLOG $a,b$ are positive integers, but you required them to be in $\Bbb N$

Comment: Ross Milikan Yes sir, I have understand my flaws. Thank you for your appreciation.